# Java Server and Client

Tags: java, eclipse

Im trying to handle this server and client programme. It should do the following dialog: [Dialoge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nvCs.png)

But sadly not working, and I dont know why. Maybe you can see the failure? I started to create a Server and a Client class but I dont know how to test it actually.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServerSource {

    static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            Scanner kyb = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            out.println("How many numbers?");
            out.flush();

            int numb = kyb.nextInt();
            out.println("Input " + numb + " lines:");
            out.flush();

            while (numb > 0) {
                numbers.add(kyb.nextInt());
                numb--;
            }

            out.println("Sum: " + sum());
            out.flush();
            out.println("Avg: " + avg());
            out.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    public static int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + numbers.get(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static double avg() {
        return sum() / numbers.size();
    }

}





import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientSource {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.210.17.189", 5555);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            out.println("Hello?");
            out.flush();

            String strIn = in.nextLine();
            out.println(strIn);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

PS: sorry for my poor english

Comment: Please mention what is the issue.. any particular point of failure

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working"? Do you get an error? If yes, then what is the error? What behavior did you expect and what exactly is the program doing differently than you expected?

Answer (score 0):

your server except number value but in client program you send it "Hello?" value. so server side got InputMismatchException exception and exit.